# Restrictions and Limitations for CiviSpark

Tags: documentation, civicrm-spark

I very recently signed-up to CiviSpark Hosting Plattform to evaluate it for future use by our organistion. Early on the way I stucked by some limitations of that Version, first of all:

1. The localisation/ language can't be changed as desired
2. Only Users with the Admin Role selected in CiviCRM can access the CiviCRM-Site

Does anybody know how to get detailed information about the limitations, restrictions and functional differencies of the Civi Spark hosted Version compared to the "native" CiviCRM

Answer (score 2):

The [sign-up page](https://civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=89) says:

- Store up to 2000 contacts
- Send up to 5000 emails per month
- Payments are only supported with three processors: PayPal, Stripe and iATS
- The interface is available in many languages.
- A few other configurations are disabled by default, such as Households and some Location Types
- It is not possible to enable other extensions than the ones provided by default.

If you can't do something on Spark, it's worth clarifying on the Spark channel on [Mattermost](https://chat.civicrm.org) whether it is an intentional limitation or just a problem with your setup.